# How to create if statement comparing boolean and string in the same statement?

Tags: java

How do I get two variables (boolean and string) into one if statement? All I was able to do is:

```
if (shop[i].getLot() == true) { 
    totalrenters += 1;
}
```

Then I'm totally blank. How do you get the if .getString("double") to work together with the .getLot in the statement so it can count and display the renter's info?

Comment: If your string is `MyString` for example you can `if (shop[i].getLot().equals('MyString'))` if `shop[i].getLot()` is actually a boolean just use `if (shop[i].getLot())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine multiple boolean tests with && or ||.  In your case

```
if (shop[i].getLot()  &&
    "double".equals(shop[i].getStorey())) {
        totalRenters++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this but using `&&` in your if statement like

```
if (shop[i].getLot() && shop[i].getStorey("single")) {
    System.out.println ("Hey, this is a single storey corner shop");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the overall `if` statement is looking for a boolean expression in the end.  That is to say, whatever is in between those parentheses must evaluate to `true` if anything is to execute inside of the if block.

Now, to your question.  If you say that `getLot()` represents whether or not it's a corner lot, then you're halfway there.

```
if(shop[i].getLot()) {
    // logic
}
```

You can omit the `== true` portion; you'd only be comparing booleans to booleans at that point, which is not necessary.

We want to add the string condition next.  I'll make this excessively simple, but there are more clever ways to do this, such as regular expressions.

If we are saying that a method `getStorey()` exists that returns `String`, then we can check to see if that particular string is equal to "double".  You can use the logical AND (`&&`) operator to combine more than one boolean condition.

```
if(shop[i].getLot() && "double".equals(shop[i].getStorey())) {
    // increment a counter here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try below:**

```
if (( "double".equals(shop[i].getStorey() ) && ( shop[i].getLot() )) {
            totalRenters++;
        }
```

Note: `shop[i].getLot()` return `true|false` so is directly working as `if(true|false)`

---

You can Add as many as condition in `if statement` base on your requirement

**Eg:**

```
String name = "Hello"
boolean isTrue = true;
```

> **Use of `&&` in `if statement`:**
>
> If you want to do something when (name is Hello **`and`** isTrue = true)
>
> `if("Hello".equals(name) && isTrue)`

---

> **Use of `||` in `if statement`:**
>
> If you want to do something when (name is Hello **`or`** isTrue = true)
>
> `if("Hello".equals(name) || isTrue)`